# how to write an aspectj itd to add an annotation to a method?

Tags: java, aspectj

I am new to aspectj but I want to write an aspectj ITD which allows me to put an annotation on

a method. Can anybody help me with it?

Thanks

Shekhar

Comment: you want to add annotation at runtime, or you want to detect annotations? And what is ITD?

Comment: ITD is intertype declaration. I have been able to do it.Please refer to my answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I was able to do it. This is how you can do it

```
declare @method :public * MyUser+.persist() : @Profiled;
```

Comment: don't rely on Google alone, read [AspectJ in Action](http://www.manning.com/laddad2/) by [Ramnivas Laddad](http://stackoverflow.com/users/485671/ramnivas). It's a fantastic reference

Answer (score 0):

this for example matches all Methods of classes which have a @Entity annotation (be sure you have the import in your aspectj-file)

```
declare @method : public * ((@Entity *)).*(..) : @PreAuthorize("denyAll");
```

but i'm having a hard time to also specify a package, suggestions?