# Can annotations be added to methods or members using AOP frameworks?

Tags: java, aop

Can I use AOP (AspectJ, Guice or other) to add annotations to classes that I cannot modify? My first use case would be adding persistence and binding annotations. I know I can write XML configuration files for JPA and JAXB but I am not aware of any way to do this for JSON binding.

I have looked for some examples/tutorials but have not found anything demonstrating this. IS it possible and if so, can someone provide a good example or better yet point me to some resources?

Comment: I am not sure I understand the syntax but according to the answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4615333/how-to-write-an-aspectj-itd-to-add-an-annotation-to-a-method) it can be done in AspectJ using [Inter-Type Declarations](http://eclipse.org/aspectj/doc/next/progguide/language-interType.html)

Comment: Did you consider writing a custom adapter for controlling the JSON Binding, rather than trying to inject annotations?

Comment: I have not. Do you have some reference I could look at? Also, this sort of thing seems to be just the type of thing AOP is meant for. It does seem there is a bit of complexity and learning curve to it. Other than that is there a reason NOT to use it?

Comment: The reason there is support for adapters, is that not everything can be done using annotations.

Comment: Do you have examples of using an adapter? Are you referring to something like [XmlAdapter](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/xml/bind/annotation/adapters/XmlAdapter.html) ?

Comment: No, I'm not talking about an *XML* adapter when I talk about *JSON* binding. What JSON annotations did you intend to inject? What JSON binding implementation did you intend to use? Look at what adapter support it has.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you can use AspectJ for that purpose (quoting the [AspectJ cheat sheet](https://eclipse.org/aspectj/doc/next/quick5.pdf), see also [AspectJ Development Kit Developer's Notebook](https://eclipse.org/aspectj/doc/next/adk15notebook/annotations-declare.html)):

- `declare @type: C : @SomeAnnotation;`
  declares the annotation `@SomeAnnotation` on the type `C`.
- `declare @method: * C.foo*(..) : @SomeAnnotation;`
  declares the annotation  `@SomeAnnotation` on all methods declared in `C` starting with `foo`.
- `declare @constructor: C.new(..) : @SomeAnnotation;`
  declares the annotation `@SomeAnnotation` on all constructors declared in `C`.
- `declare @field: * C.* : @SomeAnnotation;`
  declares the annotation `@SomeAnnotation` on all fields declared in `C`.

Just in case you wanted to ask: This feature is only supported in native AspectJ syntax, not in annotation-style @AspectJ syntax.

---

**Update:** Here is some sample code showing

- how to add annotations to classes, interfaces and methods,
- that even annotations marked as `@Inherited` are only inherited from class to subclass, never from interface to class and never to subclass methods (a typical Java caveat many developers are unaware of, see [Emulate annotation inheritance for interfaces and methods with AspectJ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42607015/emulate-annotation-inheritance-for-interfaces-and-methods) for an explanation and a possible workaround),
- how via AspectJ you can still apply an annotation to classes implementing an interface via `+` subclass specifier, e.g. in `MyInterface+`,
- how another aspect can immediately see and utilise annotations added via `declare @type`, `declare @method` etc.

**Class hierarchy including abstract base classes and an interface:**

```java
package de.scrum_master.app;

public interface MyInterface {
    void doSomething();
    int doSomethingElse(int a, int b);
    String sayHelloTo(String name);
}
```

```java
package de.scrum_master.app;

public abstract class NormalBase implements MyInterface {
    @Override
    public abstract void doSomething();

    @Override
    public int doSomethingElse(int a, int b) {
        return a + b;
    }

    @Override
    public abstract String sayHelloTo(String name);
}
```

```java
package de.scrum_master.app;

public class Normal extends NormalBase {
    @Override
    public void doSomething() {
        //System.out.println("Doing something normal");
    }

    @Override
    public String sayHelloTo(String name) {
        return "A normal hello to " + name;
    }

    public void doNothing() {
        //System.out.println("Being lazy in a normal way");
    }
}
```

```java
package de.scrum_master.app;

public abstract class SpecialBase {
    public abstract void doFoo();
    public abstract void makeBar();
}
```

```java
package de.scrum_master.app;

public class Special extends SpecialBase implements MyInterface {
    @Override
    public void doSomething() {
        //System.out.println("Doing something special");
    }

    @Override
    public int doSomethingElse(int a, int b) {
        return a * b;
    }

    @Override
    public String sayHelloTo(String name) {
        return "A special hello to " + name;
    }

    @Override
    public void doFoo() {
        //System.out.println("Doing foo");
    }

    @Override
    public void makeBar() {
        //System.out.println("Making bar");
    }

    public int doZot() {
        return 11;
    }

    public String makeBlah() {
        return "Blah";
    }
}
```

```java
package de.scrum_master.app;

public class SpecialTwo extends SpecialBase {
    @Override
    public void doFoo() {
        //System.out.println("Doing foo");
    }

    @Override
    public void makeBar() {
        //System.out.println("Making bar");
    }

    public String doXxx() {
        return "Xxx";
    }

    public int makeBlah() {
        return 22;
    }
}
```

**Driver application creating all kinds of object, calling all kinds of methods:**

```java
package de.scrum_master.app;

public class Application {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Normal instance");
        Normal normal = new Normal();
        normal.doSomething();
        normal.doSomethingElse(3, 5);
        normal.sayHelloTo("John");
        normal.doNothing();

        System.out.println("\nNormal instance as NormalBase");
        NormalBase normalBase = normal;
        normalBase.doSomething();
        normalBase.doSomethingElse(3, 5);
        normalBase.sayHelloTo("John");

        System.out.println("\nNormal instance as MyInterface");
        MyInterface myInterface = normal;
        myInterface.doSomething();
        myInterface.doSomethingElse(3, 5);
        myInterface.sayHelloTo("John");

        System.out.println("\nSpecial instance");
        Special special = new Special();
        special.doSomething();
        special.doSomethingElse(7, 8);
        special.doFoo();
        special.doZot();
        special.makeBar();
        special.makeBlah();
        special.sayHelloTo("Jane");

        System.out.println("\nSpecial instance as SpecialBase");
        SpecialBase specialBase = special;
        specialBase.doFoo();
        specialBase.makeBar();

        System.out.println("\nSpecial instance as MyInterface");
        myInterface = special;
        myInterface.doSomething();
        myInterface.doSomethingElse(7, 8);
        myInterface.sayHelloTo("Jane");

        System.out.println("\nSpecialTwo instance");
        SpecialTwo specialTwo = new SpecialTwo();
        specialTwo.doFoo();
        specialTwo.makeBar();
        specialTwo.makeBlah();
        specialTwo.doXxx();

        System.out.println("\nSpecialTwo instance as SpecialBase");
        specialBase = specialTwo;
        specialBase.doFoo();
        specialBase.makeBar();
    }
}
```

**Some marker annotations later to be added to interfaces, classes, methods by an aspect:**

```java
package de.scrum_master.app;

import java.lang.annotation.Inherited;
import java.lang.annotation.Retention;
import java.lang.annotation.RetentionPolicy;

@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Inherited
public @interface InterfaceMarker {}
```

```java
package de.scrum_master.app;

import java.lang.annotation.Inherited;
import java.lang.annotation.Retention;
import java.lang.annotation.RetentionPolicy;

@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Inherited
public @interface ClassMarker {}
```

```java
package de.scrum_master.app;

import java.lang.annotation.Inherited;
import java.lang.annotation.Retention;
import java.lang.annotation.RetentionPolicy;

@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Inherited
public @interface MethodMarker {}
```

**Aspect adding annotations to interfaces, classes, methods:**

```java
package de.scrum_master.aspect;

import de.scrum_master.app.ClassMarker;
import de.scrum_master.app.InterfaceMarker;
import de.scrum_master.app.MethodMarker;
import de.scrum_master.app.MyInterface;
import de.scrum_master.app.SpecialBase;

public aspect AnnotationGenerator {
    declare @type : MyInterface+ : @InterfaceMarker;
    declare @type : SpecialBase : @ClassMarker;
    declare @method : * say*(..) : @MethodMarker;
}
```

**Aspect logging initialisation of annotated classes and execution of annotated methods:**

```java
package de.scrum_master.aspect;

import de.scrum_master.app.ClassMarker;
import de.scrum_master.app.InterfaceMarker;
import de.scrum_master.app.MethodMarker;

public aspect MarkedObjectLogger {
    before() : @annotation(InterfaceMarker) {
        System.out.println(thisJoinPoint + " -> @InterfaceMarker");
    }

    before() : @annotation(ClassMarker) {
        System.out.println(thisJoinPoint + " -> @ClassMarker");
    }

    before() : @annotation(MethodMarker) && execution(* *(..)) {
        System.out.println(thisJoinPoint + " -> @MethodMarker");
    }
}
```

**Console log:**

```
Normal instance
staticinitialization(de.scrum_master.app.NormalBase.<clinit>) -> @InterfaceMarker
staticinitialization(de.scrum_master.app.Normal.<clinit>) -> @InterfaceMarker
execution(String de.scrum_master.app.Normal.sayHelloTo(String)) -> @MethodMarker

Normal instance as NormalBase
execution(String de.scrum_master.app.Normal.sayHelloTo(String)) -> @MethodMarker

Normal instance as MyInterface
execution(String de.scrum_master.app.Normal.sayHelloTo(String)) -> @MethodMarker

Special instance
staticinitialization(de.scrum_master.app.SpecialBase.<clinit>) -> @ClassMarker
staticinitialization(de.scrum_master.app.Special.<clinit>) -> @InterfaceMarker
staticinitialization(de.scrum_master.app.Special.<clinit>) -> @ClassMarker
execution(String de.scrum_master.app.Special.sayHelloTo(String)) -> @MethodMarker

Special instance as SpecialBase

Special instance as MyInterface
execution(String de.scrum_master.app.Special.sayHelloTo(String)) -> @MethodMarker

SpecialTwo instance
staticinitialization(de.scrum_master.app.SpecialTwo.<clinit>) -> @ClassMarker

SpecialTwo instance as SpecialBase
```

Try removing the `+` from `declare @type : MyInterface+` and see how all log lines mentioning `@InterfaceMarker` vanish because interface annotations really are not inherited by implementing classes.